# NX Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')

Tags: angular, nrwl-nx

After upgrading my Angular frontend to Angular 14 and upgrading both `@nrwl/angular` and `@nrwl/cli` `devDependencies` both to version `14.6.4`, I get the following error in terminal when I run `yarn start`

> NX Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'endsWith')

I then decided to run `nx migrate --run-migrations`

and I got:

> NX Failed to run update-ngcc-postinstall from @nrwl/angular. This
> workspace is NOT up to date!
>
> NX rule is not a function

So I set `@angular/cli` to version `14.2.1` and `@nrwl/cli` to `14.6.4`.

I ran `yarn` again, then `yarn start` and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
nx migrate @nrwl/workspace@version
```

Where version should be replaced with proper value

And refer this link to find the matching nx version

https://nx.dev/angular-nx-version-matrix

Finally run

```
nx migrate --run-migrations
```

Read for nx migrations

https://nx.dev/core-features/automate-updating-dependencies